# Rails 3.2 activerecord-jdbc-adapter error

Tags: jruby

I have just updated to rails 3.2 running on JRuby-1.6.5 and when I run rake db:migrate, I get the following error:

> undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass

Here is the trace:

> /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in
>   `to_sql'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:36:in`
>   select_values'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:571:in
>   `get_all_versions'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:729:in`
>   migrated'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in
>   `current_version'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:669:in`
>   migrate' org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:552:in `detect'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:669:in`
>   migrate'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:554:in
>   `up'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:535:in`
>   migrate'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:153:in
>   `(root)' org/jruby/RubyProc.java:258:in`call'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in
>   `execute' org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in`each'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in
>   `execute'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:201:in
>   `mon_synchronize'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in
>   `invoke'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in`
>   invoke_task'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in
>   `top_level' org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in`each'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in
>   `top_level'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in`
>   standard_exception_handling'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in
>   `top_level'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in`
>   run'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in
>   `standard_exception_handling'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in`
>   run'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in
>   `(root)' org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1073:in`load'
>   /Users/paulcowan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/bin/rake:19:in `(root)' Tasks:
>   TOP => db:migrate

The error appears to be coming from activerecord-jdbc-adapter.

I am referencing the master in my gem file:

```
gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', :git => "https://github.com/nicksieger/activerecord-jdbc-adapter.git", :branch => 'master'
```

Has anybody else had this error or it there a resolution.

Comment: did you see this thread? http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3475933

Comment: Thanks, I found a work around in this issue https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/issues/132. Thanks